# Redirect one domain to another different domain (with DNS)?

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain

Let say I have two domains: `example1.com` and `example2.com`. When I enter `www.example2.com` or `example2.com`, I want to always redirect to `www.example1.com`. I need this, because `example2.com` for now does not have its own webpage, so I need it to redirect to old webpage for now.

I can do this with DNS settings using redirection feature in DNS where I can set URL to redirect and one MX record. But if I use that, I can't use resource records like cname, A, TXT for other things in that domain. In other words I have to choose: use that redirection or resource records.

But with resource records I don't see a way how could I properply redirect. I tried something like (in `example2.com` domain):

`@ CNAME www.example1.com`

`www CNAME www.example1.com`

`@ A "IP of example1.com"`

But none of these seems to work. Am I missing something or it won't work anyway?

Comment: You can use webservers configuration to redirect request with specific URL to another url.

Comment: @JayK so I need to add that `example2.com` in webservers configuration (where old `example1.com` is set)?

Comment: Yes as you said you have to redirect request from www.example2.com to www.example1.com then you should add configuration in the www.example2.com's web server If you are using two different web server for different domain. OR just add two different virtual hosts for different domains If using single web server.

Comment: @JayK yeah, for now there is only one webserver which handles `example1.com`. Then I'll try to redirect from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this configuration on the web server itself. Some DNS hosts provide this service transparently by using web server configuration. If you have a web server you can configure yourself you can use the following Apache VirtualHost configuration...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domaina.com
  Redirect permanent / http://domainb.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But I guess, I should make `A` record that would point `example2.com` to an IP that webserver is on?

Comment: Yes it does need to be pointed to a web server. You can use the same Apache web server for both sites and simply configure the VHost file right.